# Responsive UI design causing problems for Entity Framework in Blazor application

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am familiar with writing highly responsive ASP.NET MVC applications where we load the initial page data, and then fire off multiple AJAX calls to load "secondary" data for the page.  So behinds the scenes, these AJAX requests all hit the web server(s) about the same time and pull data from our SQL DB.

I envisage doing something very similar with a Blazor application.  So, we'd load the page with some data and then have multiple components then display on the page with additional data; the loading of these components could be initialized by a user action, or by some other event(s) on the page.

And that's where I see a problem: the event handlers all react very nicely to events fired by the various components on the razor page, and they all then hit our DataService (injected into the page) which then results in lots of threads hitting our Entity Framework's Context.

And that's not allowed - only one thread may call the context at any one time.

To get around this, I can lock the Context using a SemaphoreSlip(1,1) to ensure that only one thread gets access at any one time, but that seems a bit of a bottle neck to me.  Surely locking the Context is not something that Microsoft would be expecting us to do....??

What am I missing here?

I'm using Blazor-Server, .NET Core 3.1/EF Core 3.1.  In my App's startup, I'm setting up the EF Context and the Service for DI:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
services.AddScoped<MyService>();
```

The Context is injected into the constructor of the Service (as per Microsoft's Blazor examples), and the Service is injected into the Page.

Comment: Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58047471/842935

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Scoped" services in Blazor are scoped to the client session, not to the HTTP request, as in ASP.NET.

> the Blazor Server hosting model supports the Scoped lifetime. In
>   Blazor Server apps, a scoped service registration is scoped to the
>   connection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-services-to-an-app

So you would use a "Transient" lifetime for the DbContext, or simply create your DbContext isntances as local variables in a `using` block or statement.  See

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10448

For an extended discussion of this issue.

Comment: `Transient` is not enough, [create a new scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58347502/842935) or yout approach ( use `using` ) is the way.

Comment: @David Browne: Changed from above to ``services.AddTransient<MyContext>(); services.AddScoped<MyService>();` but this threw `System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'`.   Same issue when made MyService Transient too.  Creating the context in the method worked

Comment: I posed a further comment on https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10448 regarding a new context vs locking an existing context.  I really want to understand the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: I will be posted to issue 10448 activity.

Comment: The final solution was: **Razor Page**
'@inherits OwningComponentBase<Data.MyService>' 
**Startup**
`services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
services.AddScoped<MyService>();`

Answer (score -1):

Blazor is different from MVC in that the page is "alive" all the time. Think "Windows Forms" not "Web Forms". You would not make "Ajax calls" because there is-no-postback to avoid.

See:
[Creating A Step-By-Step End-To-End Database Server-Side Blazor Application](http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4318/Creating-A-Step-By-Step-End-To-End-Database-Server-Side-Blazor-Application.aspx)

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly MyContext_context;
    public MyService(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public Task<List<WeatherForecast>>
        GetForecastAsync(string strCurrentUser)
    {
        List<WeatherForecast> colWeatherForcasts =
            new List<WeatherForecast>();
        // Get Weather Forecasts  
        colWeatherForcasts =
            (from weatherForecast in _context.WeatherForecast
                 // only get entries for the current logged in user
                 where weatherForecast.UserName == strCurrentUser
             select weatherForecast).ToList();
        return Task.FromResult(colWeatherForcasts);
    }
}
```

Comment: The link provided suggests I do what I'm already doing.

Comment: You did not indicate how you were consuming it, that part is important because while others have suggested wrapping the code that consumes it in a "using" I have found that would require the connection to be instantiated each time.